# Video files stop playing after 3 seconds in Internet explorer11

Tags: html, jsp, video, internet-explorer-11, mp4

Embedded video files stop playing after roughly 3 seconds in `IE` version `11.1206.15063.0CO`. They work in earlier versions of `IE`  version `11.0.10240.17443CO` as well as in `Google Chrome` and `Mozilla FireFox`. The `MP4` files work in all media players as well. The code is opening in an iframe when called. Here is the code that is being called.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="google" value="notranslate" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>VA Getting to the POINT Aug 18</title>

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

</style>

<link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<video width="980" height="540" controls>
    <source src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <embed src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="980" height="570" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" autoplay="false"></embed>  <!--IE 8 - add 25-30 pixels to vid height to allow QT player controls-->
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing the meta content to different `IE` versions, as well as removing the embed tag and `webm` file from inside the video tags. I have tried changing the encoding of the video file and other modifications to the html file. I am currently in the process of going through the `.jsp` file that calls the code as well. Everything I try still works in Chrome and Firefox just not this version of `IE`11.

Once in a while an error also pops up saying Error: Unsupported video type or invalid path and Error: Video could not be decoded.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue in the IE11 . IE never gets tired in creating issues which no other browsers have. 
anyone with any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

IE needs the H.264 or MPEG-4 codec and you doesn't specified them..

try below code

```
<video width="980" height="540" controls>
    <source src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="H.264/MPEG-4"/>
    <source src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <embed src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" codecs="H.264/MPEG-4" width="980" height="570" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" autoplay="false"></embed>  <!--IE 8 - add 25-30 pixels to vid height to allow QT player controls-->
</video>
```

up-to-date info, support etc available on [this link](http://html5please.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that as well does not work. Thank you for the link for the support and up to date info. It will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

As i said i also had the same issue in IE and adding preload="auto" solved my problem.
you can try something like below .

```
<video width="980" height="540" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <embed src="VA_Getting_to_the_POINT_Aug_2018.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="980" height="570" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" autoplay="false"></embed>  <!--IE 8 - add 25-30 pixels to vid height to allow QT player controls-->
</video>
```

but as adding preload may not be the great thing to do always, you can just add this attribute only in case of internet explorer for the rest you can leave as it is.